# Error When Using Manually Installed .sty Package for TeX Live [Arch Linux]

Tags: linux, latex, tex

I am trying to install mathpartir on Arch Linux. I have Tex Live installed from the repository (pdflatex version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18). I ran the .ins file through LaTeX and generated a .sty file. I have moved the .sty file to /usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mathpartir and ran texhash and mktexlsr, but when I try to run pdflatex on the file

```
\documentclass{article}
  \begin{document}
    \begin{mathpar}
    \end{mathpar}
  \end{document}
```

I get the error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Environment mathpar undefined.
```

I have also tried putting the .sty file in /usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base, in the same directory as the .tex file I am running, and in ~/texmf but nothing is working. Does anyone have any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include the package in your example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathpartir}
  \begin{document}
    \begin{mathpar}
    \end{mathpar}
  \end{document}
```

Comment: In the initial question I said that I had run both texhash and mktexlsr. Nothing seems to work.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I modified your example. Edited the answer.